# How to modify HTML element using c# without any 3rd party library?

Tags: c#, xml

As a part of a project i need to do, i read a xml file with c# and need to place the node values inside a span which has the id of the node's key.
I cannot use any 3rd party libraries (Agility Pack).
I thought of injecting jQuery to the file but i need to do it natively in the c# console application.

Comment: Why can't you use Agility Pack? It sounds like the most obvious and correct solution.

Comment: its sounds like great home work, but the thing about homework is you need to figure it out your self otherwise they would call it StrangerWork instead of Home work. You could use airtasker and pay someone to do it for you, but once again you wont learn anything. how about looking up RegEx and or similarly using indexOf and Replace

Comment: I cannot use it because of information security issues (everything is blocked, i have just the tools that are installed in the work station). I know how to solve it in couple ways but i am instructed to do the other way

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a File stream or something to read the file. Look up something that read lines, add your own code that recognizes a xml block, look up how to insert text in a string, insert your node and write the text back to the file.

If it is a website that is live: If you use c# then you have a ASP.Net site so than look something up like asp.net dynamic add controls or something and they will give you the answer.

EDIT

You have something that can read a xml file. Without a lib...? 
Write code that detects that `<></>` an html element is.

Make a class that has al the basic variables of an element:

Type: a,p,h1,h2 etc...

Id: going to be equal to the id in the html file

Value: value withing the brackets

ParentElement Id: to link the element to the element thats surrrounds the 
element

ChildElement Id List: to check if the element has child elements and wich one

How to implement this is basic C#.

Then read the file line for line. If a bracket opens withing a element that's not closed add the id as childid to the parent element child id list and set parentelement Id in the child. Basicly give everything an index so you can just search in one giant list of elements the correct element and add a value or add a new element.

Comment: too generic answer. The question is how to read the html element natively in c# and inject the value i've already extracted from the xml.

Comment: Is the html file in a live website or is it just a html file locally that doesn't do anything? A third party library would search for the object and place the value inbetween the tags, so you have to make something like that. The only native file read and write method is by using System.IO and then use streamreader and writer. But it al depends on where is the html file. If it's on a server than it's impossible because you need some sort of ftp client, and I assume that is a bit out of range for you.

Comment: And html is build the same way as a xml file(in blocks with an ID), so if you can extract something from a xml file why can you not write to a html file?